# Optimizing Pandas function for faster results Python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am trying to decrease the processing time of the `std` function below. Is there a module I could import that could decrease the processing time for this function? It calculates the standard deviation each of the the iterating 10000 values one by one. Although the `std` function is fast I am looking to perhaps decrease the processing time by half. The function turns the calculations to numpy arrays at the end.

Variables:

```
FILE = 'input.csv'
data =pd.read_csv(FILE, low_memory=False)
#reverses all the table data values
data1 = data.iloc[::-1].reset_index(drop=True)
#Columns
PC_list= np.array(data1['Close'])
number = 10000
```

Function

```
std= pd.Series(PC_list).rolling(number).std().dropna().to_numpy()
```

Performance:

[image]

Sample of the `PC_list` data frame:

```
[386.63 386.63 386.63 386.63 386.63 386.63 386.63 386.63 386.63 386.63
 386.63 386.63 386.63 386.63 386.63 386.63 386.63 386.63 386.63 386.63
 378.03 378.03 378.03 378.03 378.03 378.03 378.03 378.03 373.   370.69
 370.13 370.13 369.73 369.73 375.41 375.41 375.41 375.   375.   375.
 376.95 376.95 376.95 376.95 376.95 376.95 376.95 376.95 376.95 376.95
 376.95 376.95 376.95 376.95 376.95 376.95 376.95 376.95 376.95 376.95
 376.95 376.95 376.95 376.95 376.95 376.95 376.95 376.95 376.95 376.94
 376.52 376.52 376.52 376.52 376.52 376.52 376.52 376.52 376.52 376.52
 376.52 376.52 371.32 371.32 371.32 371.32 371.32 371.32 371.32 371.32
 370.96 370.96 370.96 377.09 377.09 377.09 377.09 378.97 374.39 374.4 ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Numba

Use a single pass algorithm

```
from numba import njit

@njit
def std(a, k):
    n = len(a)
    m = n - k + 1
    k_ = k
    mu  = np.zeros(m, np.float64)
    var = np.zeros(m, np.float64)
    mu[0]  = a[:k].sum() / k
    var[0] = ((a[:k] - mu[0]) ** 2).sum() / k_

    for i in range(1, m):
        old = a[i-1]
        new = a[i+k-1]
        d = (new - old)
        mu[i] = mu[i-1] + d / k
        old_ = mu[i-1]
        new_ = mu[i]
        var[i] = var[i-1] + d * (new + old + new_ + old_) / k_
    return mu, var ** 0.5
```

Prime the compilation of the function

```
std(np.arange(100), 10);
```

Create test data

```
np.random.seed([3, 14])
s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(1_000_000))
```

Use function

```
mu, sig = std(s.to_numpy(), 1000)
```

These results are close to `s.rolling(1000).std().dropna()` but their are numerical differences.

```
s.rolling(1000).std().dropna().sub(sig).plot()
```

[image]

The timing results

```
%timeit s.rolling(1000).std().dropna()
%timeit pd.Series(std(s.to_numpy(), 1000)[1])

28 ms ± 189 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
10.3 ms ± 42.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

You can see what Pandas is doing deep inside the bowels... [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/f2c8480af2f25efdbd803218b9d87980f416563e/pandas/_libs/window/aggregations.pyx#L364)

It isn't dissimilar but does a few more overhead checks that cost some time.  Ultimately, it is likely safer to just use what Pandas has.  But if you need something that is a tad quicker, well there you go.

Comment: Thanks do you think it would be possible to use gpu acceleration with this function